# Postgresql group and count similar words

Tags: postgresql, count, grouping

How can we group and count the number of occurrence for words that have a slight variation such as the following example?

```html
<style type="text/css">
 table.tableizer-table {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC; 
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 } 
 .tableizer-table td {
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
 }
 .tableizer-table th {
  background-color: #104E8B; 
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
 }
</style>
<table class="tableizer-table">
<thead><tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th>subject</th></tr></thead><tbody>
 <tr><td>account</td></tr>
 <tr><td>accounts</td></tr>
 <tr><td>account.</td></tr>
 <tr><td>account,</td></tr>
 <tr><td>account?</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

The desired result is this:

```html
<style type="text/css">
 table.tableizer-table {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC; 
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 } 
 .tableizer-table td {
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
 }
 .tableizer-table th {
  background-color: #104E8B; 
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
 }
</style>
<table class="tableizer-table">
<thead><tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th>subject</th><th>word_count</th></tr></thead><tbody>
 <tr><td>account</td><td>5</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

The subject column has thousands of single words so we cannot manually group each one using LIKE. Thanks.

Comment: Ask use proper tag.. Mostly in `postgresql` tag are about `database` and `query` or back-end code.. Not front-end type like this..

Comment: Thanks, @dwir182.  So, it's not possible to do in Postgresql?

Comment: if you asking about query it is simple.. `select account, count(account) as word_count from table group by account`

Comment: No, that's not the question.  Please see examples.

Comment: I am sorry.. I am not the guy can answer your question.. Maybe `css` tag people can help you.. :)